# Bash preserve whitespaces and newlines from file content to variable

Tags: bash

I have this code

```
TOKEN=$(cat ./config/token)

echo "$TOKEN"

cat > variables.env <<EOF
TOKEN=`echo "$TOKEN"`
EOF
```

I am trying to get the content of a file and output it in a new file prefixed by some text. The first `echo` in the console echoes the output I want, keeping the whitespaces and newlines.

However, in the new file the output is just the first line of the original string, while I'd like the same output I can see in the console with the first `echo`.

Comment: btw, all-caps variable names are by POSIX-specified convention used for variables with meaning to the OS or the shell itself, whereas lower-case variables are reserved for application use -- see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph, keeping in mind that environment variables and regular shell variables share a namespace (shell variables are initialized from environment variables, and setting a shell variable whose name overlaps an environment variable updates the latter automatically).

Comment: So it turns out these lines of code have been working all along as expected, both whitespaces and newlines are preserved. A different part of the system was faulty. However, I accepted an answer with a straightforward improvement to this code.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That's intended.

Comment: It's supposed to be used as an env variable.

Comment: Per the link, environment variables for application rather than OS use should have at least one lower-case character to avoid potential for conflict with new variables for OS use added in the future. "Environment variables should be all-caps" is *not* what the standard calls for.

Comment: Inasmuch as this question still lacks an acceptable answer, could you edit to add a [mcve] that provides an *actual value of `token`*, and the actual content you want to have in your output file when that value is in use?

Comment: Chill man. Any example containing newlines will do.

Comment: Not if we don't know what your intended output is. If the input is one line `hello` and a second line `world`, and the output is `TOKEN=$'hello\nworld'`, then if you run `source variables.env` and `echo "$TOKEN"`, you'll get two lines of output... but does that mean that output is *actually what you want*? Doesn't seem so, given your choice of answers, which means that what you *do* want is unclear without explicit clarifications to the question.

Comment: Moreover, if you say you want correct behavior with **any** example containing newlines, that means correct behavior with a token having a line containing, say, `$(touch /tmp/this-is-code-execution)` (making `echo "$TOKEN"` emit that exact string after a shell has read in the generated file, *not* having the code executed during evaluation and its output stored in the variable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Useless use of echo](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#echo)

This is what you could write:

```
cat > variables.env <<EOF
TOKEN=${TOKEN}
EOF
```

Comment: Doesn't protect against shell injection attacks -- assumes that `TOKEN` will be a value that doesn't get expanded or modified (or which escapes its quotes) when `variables.env` is sourced.

Comment: @feychou, the edit you proposed arguably weakens the answer. `${foo}` provides no practical advantage over `$foo`, but `"$foo"` (in this context) has the quotes copied as literal values into the output file; *if* the preexisting content of `TOKEN` doesn't have spaces escaped, those quotes may be useful. (I'm not particularly happy with this one because double quotes aren't strong enough escaping for arbitrary content -- neither are single quotes, for that matter -- but *if* the above-referenced assumptions hold, they're better than no quotes at all).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Quoting my question: I am trying to get the content of a file and output it in a new file prefixed by some text.
I did not say I wanted the value enclosed by quotes.

Comment: @feychou, ...when you specify a `.env` file, that's conventionally used for files that can be sourced into a shell to set variables. It implies some very specific formatting rules to ensure that content is parsed back to its original values correctly. If you'd said *explicitly* as part of the question that you wanted just a literal append with no escaping in the question, that would be one thing -- but in the absence of an explicit spec, it's reasonable to assume that your file will be read in the conventional way given its extension and contents (said contents looking like an assignment).

Answer (score 2):

Use `printf %q` (in ksh or bash) to escape content in such a way that it will always evaluate back to its literal value:

```
printf 'TOKEN=%q\n' "$(<./config/token)" >variables.env
```

`$(<file)` is a ksh and bash extension which acts as a more efficient replacement for `$(cat file)` (as the regular command substitution needs to fork off a subprocess, set up a FIFO, and spawn an external copy of `/bin/cat`, whereas the `$(<file)` form simply tells the shell to read the file directly).

This way a taken containing an otherwise-hostile string such as `$(rm -rf ~)` or content that could simply be expanded as a variable (`$$`) will be emitted as literal content.

---

Providing an explicit example of how this behaves:

```
printf '%s\n' "first line" "second line" >token # write two lines to the file "token"
printf 'TOKEN=%q\n' "$(<token)" >variables.env # write a shell command which assigns those
                                               # two lines to a variable to variables.env
source variables.env   # execute variables.env in the current shell
echo "$TOKEN"          # emit the value of TOKEN, as given in the current shell
```

...when run with bash, will emit the exact output:

```
first line
second line
```

...after writing the following (with bash 3.2.48; may vary with other releases) to `variables.env`:

```
TOKEN=$'first line\nsecond line'
```

Comment: Why this should be preferred instead of inserting text with `sed` or friends?

Comment: @karakfa, unless the token is pre-escaped in the input file, you need to use `printf %q` to get a value that's safely escaped whether or not you're using a tool like `sed` -- but why would you bother with the overhead of running such an external tool when the shell can do what you want internally, and you've already paid the shell's startup costs (unlike `sed`'s) when your script was invoked?

Comment: This does not preserve newlines in my case.

Comment: I understand the overhead issue, but just using file operations you're bypassing all the shell expansion and workarounds.  The performance of once in the blue moon running scripts should not be an issue, the processors are idle most of the time.

Comment: @feychou, if your input file contains two lines, `foo` and `bar`, then the output in `variables.env` will be something a shell parses as a two-line variable, whether it's escaped as `$'foo\nbar'` or as a quoted string with a literal newline.

Comment: @karakfa, I'm worried about shell expansion *when the `variables.env` file is actually used*. My workarounds aren't for the code given in the answer, they're for the benefit of whatever later runs `source variables.env` or some equivalent command to activate the file's contents.

Comment: Still not convinced, my guess is for this particular case, the generated file will be sourced to assign a literal value to the env variable TOKEN.  Perhaps OP needs to post the details as well...

Comment: @karakfa, right -- that's the point, making sure that the value is treated as literal. `printf '%q' "$value"` ensures that your value is emitted *in a way that will parse back to its current literal value, when evaluated by the same shell*.

Comment: OK, so it's actually arguing against exposing the contents of the file to the shell, which will require careful craft to leave it unmodified.

Comment: @karakfa, exactly right. A `.env` file is *typically* read by something that'll perform shell-like parsing, and if that's the case, then careful cruft is called for.

Answer (score 0):

you are doing it in a very convoluted way, there are easier methods

```
sed '1s/./TOKEN=&/' file > newfile
```

will insert `TOKEN=` on the first line.  This has an additional benefit of not modifying empty files (at least one char should exist in the original file).  If that's not intended you can use unconditional insert.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
echo "TOKEN=" > newfile && cat ./config/token >> newfile
```

- `>>` appends to a file.

Comment: Vulnerable to shell injection, and needlessly bad performance (re-opening the output file twice instead of using only a single file handle). Also, this adds a newline between the `TOKEN=` and the value.

Comment: `{ printf 'TOKEN='; cat ./config/token; } >newfile` will open `newfile` only once (vs once with `O_TRUNC`, closing the file, and then opening it a second time with `O_APPEND`), and will also avoid that newline. (One could use `echo -n` instead of `printf` on bash, but that's not robust on all POSIX shells; the POSIX standard for `echo` specifies that output is undefined when `-n` is present, not that it has any particular behavior).